# Windows 8.1 PC leeching all internet speed from other computers when downloading

Tags: mac, windows-8.1, internet

My father recently replaced his game-PC, for sim-racing, to a brand new one with Windows 8.1 installed. At home we have two other computers, both iMac's, and all three computers are plugged into the Ethernet ports of our modem, so our internet is wired and not coming through WiFi.

This was our set-up already with his older PC, but since his upgrade, every single time my father wants to download something for a game, may it be a patch for a car, or something through Steam, the internet-speed for the other computer users simply seizes to be, his computer hogging it all.

When it comes to Steam, we've found in the settings that we can limit its download speed, and that fixes the issue in that case, but whenever he just manually downloads something through Firefox, it just eats up all the speed and we can't even load the standard Google page on the other computers.

Does anyone know what may be causing this problem, and even better, if there is a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for a QoS setting in your router; switch it on. it should share out the bandwidth more fairly.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to *throttle* his download speed, one easy way is to install a download manager on his Windows 8.1 machine, e.g. [Free Download Manager (FDM)](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) and many others; see [Alternatives To FDM](http://alternativeto.net/software/free-download-manager/). FDM and some of the others have settings to control number of simultaneous connections and network speed, and have preset buttons to make selection of *traffic usage mode* easier.

Note that the user can select any speed setting, or bypass a download manager, so this depends on your father's coopderation. ;-)

This was especially helpful when I was restricted to dial-up connection speed.